# Selecting Multiple Videos

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

As of now I can only select one video, wait for it to compress and then save that video to my server. Is there any way I can select many videos all at the same time and then take those and upload them to a server?

In my interface:

```
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImagePickerController *uploadPicker;
```

And how I set the picker:

```
    uploadPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]; 
    uploadPicker.delegate = self;
    uploadPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    uploadPicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
    uploadPicker.videoMaximumDuration = 300.0f;
    [self presentViewController:uploadPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The picker is only for single images or videos. You will need to create your own or you can use [ELCImagePickerController](https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController) to choose multiple video.

In ELCAlbumPickerController.m, find `[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]`. There should be two instances of this. You should be able to show videos if you replace them by `[ALAssetsFilter allVideos]` or, if you want both photos and videos, `[ALAssetsFilter allAssets]`.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly not, the picker is only for single images or videos. You will need to create your own to simulate the normal photo album.
look at this link may help you [ELCImagePickerController](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/07/cloning-uiimagepickercontroller-using-the-assets-library-framework/).